# Java: try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) { } causing an exception

Tags: java, debugging, java.util.scanner

Using `try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) { }` is causing

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

When I try to debug it says that

> Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option.

and shows the below code

```
    public Scanner(InputStream source) {
    this(new InputStreamReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
  }
```

One of my methods that uses this line:

```
protected String loginName(){
    String username;
    String password;
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) { // This line is causing the error.
      System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
      username = scan.next();
      System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
      password = scan.next();
    }
    if(getUsernamesList().contains(username))

        if(password.equals(getPasswordsList().get(getUsernamesList().indexOf(username)))) return username;
        else return "-1";

    else return "-1";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need to try-with-resource for that

Comment: should not the try block be inside curly braces?

Comment: @hermit what do you mean? it is in curly braces, it just hasn't been indented

Comment: I had not used try(statement){} structure before.

Comment: @hermit it's called a try with resource, very helpful, it makes sure that a resource you're using is closed if an exception occurs

Comment: @Aequitas: thanks for the information.It is helpful.

Comment: @harout tatarian did you debug it in cmd ?? don't you have a ide ?

Comment: @Fast Snail To be honest this is the first time I'm debugging, and Yes I did it with an IDE. why is your question? I'm guessing that I did something wrong lol

Comment: `Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option.`  when you debug ide will compile using -g option .i don't know but i have never get this when i debug in de

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what the -g option is?

Comment: @HaroutTatarian when you compile with -g for instance `javac myclass.java -g` will genarate debugging information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're closing `System.in` (a global-variable). **Please**, do not do that. Everywhere you have

```
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in))
```

guarantees that `System.in` will be `close`(d). Once it's `close`(d) you can't read from it again (or you get your mentioned `Exception`). Also, you can compile with debug symbols (or step into it with your IDE's built-in debugger or [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) as applicable). The [`Scanner.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--) Javadoc says (in part),

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying [readable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html) also implements the [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface then the readable's `close` method will be invoked

Comment: Shouldn't it only cause a problem if you try using it again (after it's been closed)?

Comment: Constructing an instance of `Scanner` with a `close`(d) `InputStream` **is** using it again.

Comment: Does that mean that the 'Scanner' is instantly being closed because I'm declaring it with a try-with resources?

Comment: @HaroutTatarian No, it just doesn't reopen after the very first time you have a method that closes it with a try-with-resources.

Comment: Aha! So I should use this Only and Only if I don't need it again later on right?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but it's only being used in the try() so how would there be a problem? You're only using it inside the try block, then it's closed. and it should be fine to close it if you're not using it?

Comment: Because `System.in` is a global, when you close it it will not re-open the next you try to read it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but I'm not getting the exception the second time I'm using it, I'm getting it also on the first time.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian Use a debugger. And is `loginName()` the very first method you call?

Comment: No, It is the second one.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian And does the first one also close `System.in`?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Yes, It does have a System.in method declared in a try-with resources, and the error does not occur in the first one but it does in the second one because it is a global variable. I finally got your answer right? thank you very much !

Comment: @HaroutTatarian Constructing multiple scanners on a single input stream may cause conflicts, since they'll all consume input trying to read ahead. Much better to pass either the `Scanner` object or the read values to the method.

Comment: @Aequitas I figured out the answer and I felt that you're interested. The problem is that I'm closing the System.in on a previous method and System.in is a Global Object cannot be opened once closed so the error occurs in the second method.

Comment: Ah yes, if you have another method calling it, then it makes sense, but as the code stands it should work. Maybe add to the question that you have the same try-with-resources else where in your code and it works fine there. This will help future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried not using the try?

```
String username;
String password;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
```

Comment: Yes, That doesn't cause any problems.