# Java: How to use System.in Several times in one program?

Tags: java, system.in

On my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042139/java-tryscanner-scan-new-scannersystem-in-causing-an-exception/) I've learned that I shouldn't close the `System.in`, and I also learned that using multiple `Scanner` together can cause problems.
The problem is that I need some methods recursively to use the `Scanner` to scan some inputs from the user.

**Example**

```
public void usersChoice(){
    int choice = 0;
    while(true){
        try{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
            choice = scan.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!\n");
            }
        }

    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            choiceNewAccount();
            break;
        case 2:
            choiceLogin();
            break;
        case 3:
            choiceRemoveAccount();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!\n");
            break;     
   }
```

**Case 1:**

```
public void createAccount(){
    try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Your Username: ");
        String username = scan.next();       
        if(!isValidUsername(username)) System.out.println("Username Already Exists!");
        else{
            while(true){
                System.out.print("Enter Your Password: ");
                String pass1 = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Re-Enter Your Passowrd: ");
                String pass2 = scan.next();
                if(!arePasswordsMatch(pass1,pass2)) System.out.println("Passowrds Don't Match!");
                else {
                    addToAccountsList(username,pass1);
                    createTheUsersFile(username);
                    System.out.println("The Account Has Been Successfully Created!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could Not Create Account!");
        }
```

Do I need to create one System.in Object and use it on my whole program? Or is there an other way to work with the System.in Object?

Comment: Just send the Scanner as argument, recreating it from System.in hardcoded is really bad practice

Comment: What amit says. Also you do not "**create** one `System.in` object", you just reference it.

Comment: I've edited the title, I don't know why I've written the title of my previous question. @Tom